# Autorespond to SMS received through broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, sms

I am doing application on autoresponder, I mean, am receiving sms and sending reply automatically, where user choose when he is busy? my problem is, in broadcast receiver, after receiving sms, I put a toast, where user has to respond whether to respond or not? after clicking ok, he has to send reply? how to sort this? how to send a reply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

[Android : Sending an SMS (using the Outbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179164/android-sending-an-sms-using-the-outbox)

http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SMS/Sender/