# Saving sent sms

Tags: c#, sms, xamarin.android

I'm able to send SMS using

```
var smsMgr = Android.Telephony.SmsManager.Default; 
smsMgr.SendTextMessage(num, null, txt, null, null);
```

but this message is not shown on sent sms list.
So I tried

```
var values = new ContentValues(); 
values.Put("address", num); 
values.Put("body", txt); 
try 
{ 
  ContentResolver.Insert(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://sms/sent"), values); 
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

having in my code

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.SEND_SMS")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.WRITE_SMS")]
```

But everytime I get `SecurityException`.
Side note: my phone has not root *permission*.
What can I do?

Comment: Please, read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179164/android-sending-an-sms-using-the-outbox I hope it helps you

Comment: @MikkaRin: thanks, I'll try in the next days :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I discovered how to let sms appear on sent tab: I needed

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.READ_SMS")]
```

I don't know if this is a requirement of every phone or Android version, but adding that permission everything worked properly!!

Answer (score 1):

```
private void addSENTSMS(String address, String message) {
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("address", address);
            values.put("body", message);
            getContentResolver()
                    .insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Also make sure you are using the following permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
```

Comment: The above code works fine in all versions and API levels. I have already used the following code snippet in many of my apps.

Comment: I should have permission, 'cause I set that in my app as you can see in the question. What's the difference (in your opinion) between `ContentResolver.Insert` and `getContentResolver().insert`?

Comment: Another question: should I have the root of my phone to use that? Is there some reason for which `WRITE_SMS` permission can't be granted?
Sorry, but I can test your code only in a few hours, but not now...

Comment: @Marco both are same , but while using ContentResolver.Insert returns null most of times , so more appropriate way to query content resolver is 2nd one(code snippet shared by me). Also for writing SMS , there is no need to route the phone. You just need to provide the required permission in the manifest.

Comment: I dont have `getContentResolver()`... where do you get it? Which language are you using?!? Sorry, but honestly I don't understand... am I missing some reference?

Comment: @Marco no need. e.printStackTrace() is just to print print the details of occurred exception. Use console statement as supported in your case

Comment: m using Java based ,SDK , instead use  getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()

Comment: But I'm using C#, Mono for Android!! :(

Comment: ok but I guess the syntax and dial-acts are same in either cases. :(

Comment: Syntax I used should do exactly what you do with Java... this is what I'm asking... but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Sorry but can't assist you out of your problem. It was a well working and tested code so I shared that.

Comment: Look at my answer... don't ask me the reason, but that's what I needed to let it work :(

Comment: ok nice to see gr8 work :) finally u discovered the solution.

Comment: Did you ever needed that permission to save sms on sent tab?

Comment: Actually my app was intended to perform several operation as well. So, I was already using permission.READ_SMS

Answer (score 0):

why I have compilation error "The name 'getContentResolver' does not exist in the current context" for **getContentResolver.Insert(...)** in method implemented in class MainActivity:Activity?